# Angular: How to create a validation error(radio buttons should be highlighted in red) on radio buttons when user submits an empty form

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

This issue is already posted in guthub but I do not see a resolution there.
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11333

Was hoping if there is any workaround.

https://mat-radio-group-validation.stackblitz.io/

This link will explain the error.
When a user submits an empty form, the text field gets highlighted in red. But the radio buttons do not get highlighted.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, please include a summary of your question with code sample instead of just a link, it will help people answer your directly. All the more that the GitHub issue is closed.

Answer (score 4):

Just add in your styles.scss (or in your styles.css)

```
.mat-radio-group.ng-invalid.ng-touched .mat-radio-outer-circle {
    border-color: red;
}
.mat-radio-group.ng-invalid.ng-touched .mat-radio-label-content {
     color: #f44336;
     border-bottom: 2px solid #f44336;
}
```

Then, in submit mark as touched

```
  submit(form: FormGroup) {
    if (form.valid){
       .....
    }
    else 
       this.form.markAllAsTouched();
  }
```

You can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pbtfxh?file=src%2Fstyles.scss)

NOTE1: it's necesary "force" to markAsTouched the radio group.
NOTE2: Your stackblitz don't allow see code

Comment: Worked for me. only have to add ::ng-deep  before CSS class